# Initialization function of prototype is working but change event not working

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I have a file named abc.js whose code is

```
var Calculator = Class.create();
Calculator.prototype = {
    initialize: function () {
      alert('initialize');
    },    
    calculate: function () {
      alert('Calculate on change');
    }       
}
```

and a html file having dropdown

```
<select name="calculator_select" id="calculator_select" onchange="calculator.calculate()">
```

and i have created calculator object

```
 var calculator = new Calculator();
```

When page gets loaded,initialization function of Calculator.prototype is called and it alerts initialize but onchange of dropdown calculator.calculate() doesnot respond.

Comment: Look in the browser error console when you change the dropdown and see what you see.  My guess is that the `calculator` variable isn't in the right scope (it must be in the global scope for your code to work the way it is currently structured) so `calculator.calculate()` doesn't get called because it can't find the `calculator` variable.  But, that's just a guess.  The browser error console should give you some clues.

Comment: Browser console does not give any error but can suggest the changes required according to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xRXE4/

A few hints:

-stop adding events inline (use `addEventListener`, `jquery`'s `on`)

-use `console.log` and open up console (F12)

-include the code that uses `DOM` elements inside `$(document).ready()`

```
var Calculator = Class.create();

Calculator.prototype = {
    initialize: function () {
      console.log('initialize');
    },    
    calculate: function (e) {
      console.log('Calculate on change');
    }       
}

var calculator = new Calculator();

var selectEl = document.getElementById("calculator_select");

selectEl.addEventListener('change', function() {
     calculator.calculate();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

[addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

Answer (score 0):

The same example with PrototypeJS, and with improvements from me.

```
var Calculator = Class.create({
    initialize: function (element) {

      //define a property on the class
      this.element = $(element);

      //call another method on this class
      this.setuplistener();

      console.log('initialize');
    },
    setuplistener : function(){
        this.element.observe('change',this.calculate);
    },
    calculate: function (e) {
      console.log('Calculate on change');
    }       
});

document.observe('dom:loaded',function(){

    //make sure a new instance is created after the DOM is ready
    var calculator = new Calculator($('calculator_select'));

});
```